# How many ways can you pick exactly the same 4 people from a group of 20

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The question is what is the probability that Barbara, Carl, Georg, and Henrietta are randomly chosen from a set of twenty clients for a four-person group date if all possible choices are equally likely?

I know the formula is P = Favorable outcomes / possible outcomes. For whatever reason I am not sure how to get the numerator. The possible outcomes is $20 \choose {4}$ $= 4845$, but the numerator is alluding me. It is not a multiplication rule because it doesn't allow for repeating, it can't be a permutation because order doesn't matter, leaving a combination I think. but then I did $20 \choose 4$ $\times$ $19 \choose 4$ $\times$ $18 \choose 4 $$\times$ $17 \choose 4$

I got $\frac{116280}{4845}$, which is a number larger than $1$.

What method am I missing? How do I get the number of ways I can exactly pick the Barbara, Carl, Georg, and Henrietta?

Comment: The numerator is just $1$; there is only one group of four we consider to be favourable in this scenario.

Comment: So even though it could be any combination of the 4 it's still only 1 group and therefore only 1 favorable result? so the probability would be 1/4845?

Comment: Yes, 20C4 counts the number of unordered groups of 4 among the 20 people.

Comment: As an aside, what your intuition may have been telling you to do was $\dfrac{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{20\times 19\times 18\times 17}$ which is of course equal to the right answer as well in a different form.

Comment: My intuition was telling me to take your denominator and divide that by the 20C4, which now I see why that was incorrect.  Thank you,  your formula makes it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do it by using combinations:
There are $4845$ of picking $4$ people from $20$ (order doesn't matter). Out of those $4845$, there is only **one** possibility of picking Barbara, Carl, Georg and Henrietta.

Therefore, there is a $\frac{1}{4845}$ chance that those 4 will be picked.

Comment: This must be why the professor said it's easier than I think. This makes sense, because there is no order there is only 1 possibility of picking that specific group.   Thank you for the explanation.